# iOS RestKit Manual Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, restkit

I am trying to manually integrate RestKit in my project (cocoa pods is not an option for me ATM). But I am getting these errors:

[image: error output]

I have followed tutorial for it, the one at raywenderlich [Introduction to RestKit Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial) and then after that I followed the one on the Github website [Installing RestKit v0.20.x as a Git Submodule](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule) (both are exactly the same and goes without saying but both gave same error). If some one know how to fix this or will it even work with manual integration anymore, I would really like to try RestKit Framework.

Comment: The error is related to Cocoapods but you say you want to install Restkit manually. Are you sure you're working on a clean project?

Comment: Yes, I just created a new xcode project both times I tried. And followed the steps from scratch (from git init command). It only takes around 5 mins. If some one can also try the manual integration with the latest version there. And let me know if it worked for them, it might help me understand what I did wrong.